# Jquery Menu - change to mouseover

Tags: jquery

I don't use JQuery much and in this case it is a menu created through a menu builder, my problem is i'm trying to change it from an ONCLICK trigger to a mouseover/mouseout function. I'm not posting all the variations I've tried because its a lot and most were non functional, I did get a functional version code using MOUSEOVER AND MOUSEOUT in the JQuery but it resulted in this strange bouncing effect where the menu would expand/close/expand/close/expand even though there was no mouse movement in/out of the menu after the initial mouseover occurred. IF someone can look at the last code I edited and advise where I'm approaching it wrong and the correct code I would appreciate it.

Here is the original JQuery code:

```
( function( $ ) {
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#cssmenu li.has-sub>a').on('click', function(){
        $(this).removeAttr('href');
        var element = $(this).parent('li');
        if (element.hasClass('open')) {
            element.removeClass('open');
            element.find('li').removeClass('open');
            element.find('ul').slideUp();
        }
        else {
            element.addClass('open');
            element.children('ul').slideDown();
            element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp();
            element.siblings('li').removeClass('open');
            element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('open');
            element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp();
        }
    });
});
} )( jQuery );
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="cssmenu">
<ul>
   <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>OUR SERVICES A</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="service1.html" class="cold"><span>SERVICE 1</span></a></li>
         <li><a href="service2.html" class="hot"><span>SERVICE 2</span></a></li>
         <li><a href="#" class="clean"><span>SERVICE 3</span></a></li>
         <li class="last"><a href="#" class="icy"><span>SERVICE 4</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>OUR SERVICES B</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>SERVICE 1</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="#"><span>SUB SERVICE 1</span></a></li>
               <li class="last"><a href="#"><span>SUB SERVICE 2</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>SERVICE 2</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="#"><span>SUB SERVICE 1</span></a></li>
               <li class="last"><a href="#"><span>SUB SERVICE 2</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#"><span>About Us</span></a></li>
   <li class="last"><a href="#"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here is the last version I had limited but quirky success at:

```
( function( $ ) {
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#cssmenu li.has-sub>a').on('mouseover', function(){
        $(this).removeAttr('href');
        var element = $(this).parent('li');
        if (element.hasClass('open')) {
            element.removeClass('open');
            element.find('li').removeClass('open');
            element.find('ul').slideUp();
        }
        else {
            element.addClass('open');
            element.children('ul').slideDown();
            element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp();
            element.siblings('li').removeClass('open');
            element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('open');
            element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp();
        }
    });

$('#cssmenu li.has-sub>a').on('mouseout', function(){
        $(this).removeAttr('href');
        var element = $(this).parent('li');
        if (element.hasClass('open')) {
            element.removeClass('open');
            element.find('li').removeClass('open');
            element.find('ul').slideUp();
        }
        else {
            element.addClass('open');
            element.children('ul').slideDown();
            element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp();
            element.siblings('li').removeClass('open');
            element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('open');
            element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp();
        }
    });


});
} )( jQuery );
```

I'm just trying to get the "expand" to occur ONMOUSEOVER  and the "collapse" to occur on ONMOUSEOUT. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: ur code here is Fantastic http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hEGxA ..What is problemm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps

have modified the jquery you have written to perform the sliding of the menu's

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#cssmenu li.has-sub a").on('mouseenter', function () {
     //this line finds the 'ul' which is inside the 'li' which has the class 
     //'has-sub',then slidedown the 'ul' and add a class check to it
     $(this).next('ul').slideDown().addClass('check');
   });
   $("#cssmenu li.has-sub ul").on('mouseleave', function () {
     //when mouseleave the 'ul' check if the 'ul' has class 'check', then 'slideup' 
     //the that 'ul' and remove the class check;
     if ($(this).hasClass('check')) {
        $(this).slideUp().removeClass('check');
     }
   });
});
```

Css

```
#cssmenu {
  width:250px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu li.active ul {
  display: block;
}
```

i prefer using mouseleave and mouseenter, then mouseover and mouseout. Check this [website](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1805-jquery-events-mouseover-mouseout-vs-mouseenter-mouseleave.htm) for more details.

here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TAqzF/7/)