# Variable menu length

Tags: javascript, jquery

Brand new to jquery.  I'm trying to make a drop-down animated menu that opens up just enough to show submenus while dropping the menu items as well.  For example:

```
Item1
Item2
Item3
```

And when you mouse over Item2 you get

```
Item1
Item2
  Subitem1
  Subitem2
Item3
```

I know my code needs a lot more work (I'm playing/experimenting now) and my problem is when trying to use a variable the menu doesn't open up at all so the problem is somewhere with the height: variable line.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  //When mouse rolls over
  $("li").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({height: $('ul > li').length * 20})
  });

//When mouse is removed
$("li").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({height:'18px'})
});
});
```

I'd actually prefer to make separate variable lines such as

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var numitems = $('ul > li').length;
var totalheight = numitems * 20;
  //When mouse rolls over
  $("li").mouseover(function(){
  $(this).stop().animate({height: totalheight})
  });

  //When mouse is removed
  $("li").mouseout(function(){
  $(this).stop().animate({height:'18px'})
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle, please?

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/4r2M8/

Comment: you can try slideup and slidedown to achieve this process, refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961014/jquery-menu-change-to-mouseover?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var numitems = $('ul > li').length;
var totalheight = (numitems * 20)+'px';
  //When mouse rolls over
  $("li").mouseover(function(){
  $(this).stop().animate({height: totalheight},500); //don't forget to give the animation some duration
  });

  //When mouse is removed
  $("li").mouseout(function(){
  $(this).stop().animate({height:'18px'},500);
  });
});
```

Comment: Update
I think I got a solution

    $(document).ready(function(){
    var itemheight = 30;

 //When mouse rolls over
    $("li").mouseover(function(){
 var numitems = $(this).children().children().length;
  var newheight = numitems * itemheight + 18;
 $(this).stop().animate({height:newheight},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'swing'});
    });
 
    //When mouse is removed
    $("li").mouseout(function(){
  //change totalheight back to 18;
        $(this).stop().animate({height:'18px'});
    });
 

    });

I'm not sure on the functionality differences between using > and .children()

Answer (score 0):

Forget about trying to store the height of the elements and multiplying up.  You will run into serious problems if you do this in the future.

You can always get the height of an element with jQuery's outerHeight() property. But if you want this to happen on the mouse enter/out, you would be tidier with the .hover() function of jQuery and do the following :

```
var speed = 500;
$("li.top").hover(function () {
    var ul = $(this).find("ul");
    $(ul).stop(); // stop any current animation

    // tidy up attributes that have been added
    $(ul).removeClass("flattened");
    $(ul).css("height", ""); // very necessary;
    $(ul).css("display", ""); // very necessary;
    $(ul).removeClass("show");

     var _height = $(ul).outerHeight();
    $(ul).addClass("flattened");
    $(ul).addClass("show");
    $(ul).show();

    $(ul).animate({ height: _height }, speed , function () {
        $(ul).removeClass("flattened");
    });

}, function () {
    var ul = $(this).find("ul");
    $(ul).stop();

    $(ul).animate({ height: "0px" }, speed , function () {
        $(ul).hide();
        $(ul).css("height", ""); // very necessary;
        $(ul).css("display", ""); // very necessary;
        $(ul).removeClass("show");                
    });
});
```

I used the following CSS to make things work in my test file:

```
ul li a { float: left; width: 100%; }
ul li > ul { display: none;float:left;  }
ul li { float: left; width: 100%; border: solid 1px black; min-height: 0; }
.flattened { height: 0px; overflow:hidden; }
```

And the following HTML:

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li class="top"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li class="top"><a href="#">Item 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">SubItem 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SubItem 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>        
    <li class="top"><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Hope this works for you.